# Pass javascript created checkboxes to controller to save to tabel?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have check boxes that are dynamically created form a google maps search result. I want to be able to pass these to the controller so they can be added to a database and then queried later.

Right now I have a View for a user to search for a city, the input is sent back to the controller to render a new view to populate a google map with nearby locations. The nearby locations are added dynamically to a `<div>` using javascript  as check boxes.

I have tried to pass the check boxes as a string array and array of my model class. I only receive the results in the controller using string[] but then i cannot save them to the database.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Itinerary(string[] destination)
    {
        foreach (var item in destination)
        {
            _context.Itinerary.Add(item);  // error: '"Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'string ' to NameSpace.Model.Itinerary"
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

Javascript check boxes

```
function createMarkers(places) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var placesList = document.getElementById('places');
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
        var image = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: place.name,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "destination";
        checkbox.value = place.name;
        checkbox.id = "id";
        checkbox.setAttribute("asp-for","LocationName");


        var label = document.createElement('label')
        label.htmlFor = "id";
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(place.name));


        placesList.appendChild(label);
        placesList.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Form Posting checked boxes back to controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Itinerary", "Itinerary", FormMethod.Post))
{ 

        <div multiple id="places" > </div>
        <button id="more">More results</button>

    <input type="submit" value="Finished"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out the error is on this line:

```cs
 _context.Itinerary.Add(item);  // error: '"Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'string ' to NameSpace.Model.Itinerary"
```

You need to create an `Itinerary`:

```cs
 _context.Itinerary.Add(new Itinerary { Destination = item });
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the help!